# Cave spider trap issues

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a cave spider spawner and it works great other than the area where I hit them. I've tried several designs but they can still hit me. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
This is my current setup:
[image]
The spiders climb to the top of that hole where they are crushed down to one hit. The problem is no matter where I am around the hole I get hit and poisoned is there a way I can stop them from hitting me? I need a design that prevents them from hitting me that is my question does anyone have a design?

Comment: can you show us what your setup looks like or something?

Comment: The best way I can describe it is a 2x2 hole with glass panes above it like over each of the different air blocks the hole is 2 blocks deep and spider will go to the top of the hole to be crushed then killed the only problem is when I get close to the glass panes I get hit I don't know why the glass panes stop normal spiders from hitting me but it isn't working with cave spiders I am trying to figure out a design that will prevent the spiders from hitting me.

Comment: which resource pack is that?

Comment: It's on Xbox one and it's the fantasy texture pack in going to try the slap design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a design that appears to work you still get hit but it's only if you want to get hit. Meaning if you purposely go into the areas where they can hit you. If you go to this link you can find the video I watched to discover this design. Thank you all for all of the help. Here is the link:

Answer (score -1):

Try blocking an area so they can't touch you. But at least too be able to attack them. You can use fences for they need to climb a solid block.

Comment: Currently I have a 2x2 hole with glass panes floating over the hole. I know this works with regular spiders ,but it doesn't appear to work with cave spiders. Is what I have anything like what you are describing?

Comment: Spiders climb fences with an Yao Ming face. They climb any block that is solid in collision sense, not opaque in transparency sense. Also, "build something so they can't hit you" does not exactly help someone who asks for a "design that prevents them from hitting me".

Comment: `Spiders climb fences with an Yao Ming face` Um, I'm sure your crazy because I don't know what that is.

Comment: @JimJones So, when you don't know something and can't be bothered to copy it into Google - that means someone is crazy? Also, "you're crazy",  not "your" :-P

Answer (score -1):

Today I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnALOZ3Ip50) video. now saw your question and took part of that video which was useful

Use half slabs and stairs as shown in this image.

[image]

Comment: This design does not work as the spiders can escape in that design....

Comment: Normal Spiders can not fit through 0.5 meter high gap, but Cave Spiders this question is about can.

Comment: cave spiders **Can** go through 0.5 high gap **?**